# Why does adding CPU cores make programs run faster?

Tags: cpu, multi-core, cpu-speed, clockspeed, core

Intel currently offers a 5.5GHz CPU, which represents the number of instructions the CPU can execute over time.

If a CPU has more than one core, it can execute more than one process at a time.

However, is it true that a given program can not take advantage of that, unless it has been explicitly designed to use concurrency, by splitting up its tasks into separate processes?

Or can the operating system automatically distribute a single program over multiple cores? My guess is no, because later stages of the program depend on completion of earlier stages.

Does this mean that increasing CPU cores will not make a program run faster, unless you design the program to use multiprocessing?

Comment: No a process doesn't have to be "splitted up its tasks into separate processes" to make use of multiple cores. A process can make multiple threads to make use of multiple cores. Only multi-threading incapable programming languages like JavaScript / Node.JS have to make use multiple process as the language has the "defect" (IMHO) that there are no threads.

Comment: Just anecdotally, I used to work support on an app [an online game] that was badly threaded; it made it a real core-hog. The 'fix', if you had a powerful enough machine, was to run the app twice, one just backgrounded & ignored. That gave the OS's thread scheduler a much easier time of it all & allowed it to spread the load better. File under 'strange but true'.

Comment: @Robert, different OS have different cost of creating threads and processes. For instance, it might be very costly to fork a process and easy to make a thread in some OS, and both being almost the same in another OS, so programs for the first (I'd say "defective") OS will be better using threads whenever possible, and for the second OS processes are better because this is easier to do right and it is more secure, while properly implementing multithreading is hard. Needless to say Windows is "of the defective type".

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that increasing CPU cores will not make a program run faster, unless you design the program to use multiprocessing?

That's exactly how it is. However, you can make use of more CPU cores anyway, because you (or the OS) aren't just running one program at a time. Only once you have more CPU cores than ready-to-run programs are there no more benefits to be had.

Most non-trivial software nowadays is multithreaded already.

Comment: Some programs can easily be made multi-threaded by choosing appropriate libraries. If you use [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) libraries for C++ for example, many tasks are automatically threaded without much if any work from the main program.